# How to properly serialize query params?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

In order to retrieve the current query params, I'm using this:

```js
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';

function useQuery() {
    return new URLSearchParams(useLocation().search);
}
```

Then in the functional component:

```js
const query = useQuery();
```

However, I didn't find any integrated solution to easily set `Link` to the same query params except one with a new value.

Here is my solution so far:

```
const filterLink = query => param => value => {
  const clone = new URLSearchParams(query.toString());
  clone.set(param, value);
  return `?${clone.toString()}`;
}

return (
  <>
    <Link to={filterLink(query)('some-filter')('false')}>False</Link>
    <Link to={filterLink(query)('some-filter')('true')}>True</Link>
  </>
)
```

I have to clone the `query` object in order not to mutate the original one and have unwanted side effects when calling multiple times `filterLink` in the JSX. I also have to add the question mark myself because [`URLSearchParams.prototype.toString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams/toString) does not add it.

I am wondering why I have to do that myself? I don't really like to do so low-level things when using a framework. Did I miss something in react-router? Is there a more common practice to do what I need?

Comment: What sort of "up-to-date answer" are you looking for? Are you still using `react-router@5` or are you looking for something that now uses `react-router@6`? Is the goal here to still use a `Link` component that "injects" specific queryString params into the link target path? Do you need to preserve existing query params? Do you want/need the queryString visible as part of the link's accessibility text?

Comment: I'd like a general answer about the current practices in React. As an Angular developer, I'm used to the Angular HTTP client library that provides a convenient way to handle query params while being integrated to the framework, so I'm wondering what's the equivalent in React

Comment: I guess my question is directed more to understanding the exact behavior you are wanting/expecting. Angular is a framework while React is considered more a library. As such, React is a little more DYI. React doesn't care about the URL queryString, and `react-router` is mainly interested in the URL path for route matching and rendering.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Angular is a framework while React is generally considered to still be a library. As such, React is a little more Do It Yourself (DIY). React doesn't care about the URL queryString, and `react-router` is mainly interested in the URL path for route matching and rendering.

***However***, `react-router-dom@6` introduced a few new hooks and utility functions to help work with the queryString parameters. One utility that you may find helpful in this endeavor is the [`createSearchParams`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/utils/create-search-params) function.

> ```
> declare function createSearchParams(
>   init?: URLSearchParamsInit
> ): URLSearchParams;
> ```
>
> `createSearchParams` is a thin wrapper around `new URLSearchParams(init)` that adds support for using objects with array
> values. This is the same function that `useSearchParams` uses
> internally for creating `URLSearchParams` objects from
> `URLSearchParamsInit` values.

Based on your question and the other answers here I'm assuming you don't simply need to blow away previously existing search params and replace them with the current link, but rather that you want to possibly conditionally merge new parameters with any existing params.

Create a utility function that takes the same props as the `Link` component's `to` prop (`string | Partial<Path>`). It's the [partial `Path`](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/blob/main/packages/router/history.ts#L32-L50) types we care about and want to override.

```
import { createSearchParams, To } from "react-router-dom";

interface CreatePath {
  pathname: string;
  search?: {
    [key: string]: string | number;
  };
  hash?: string;
  merge?: boolean;
}

const createPath = ({
  hash,
  merge = true,
  pathname,
  search = {}
}: CreatePath): To => {
  const searchParams = createSearchParams({
    ...(merge
      ? (Object.fromEntries(createSearchParams(window.location.search)) as {})
      : {}),
    ...search
  });

  return { pathname, search: searchParams.toString(), hash };
};
```

Usage:

1. Link that merges params with existing queryString params:

   ```
   <Link to={createPath({ pathname: "/somePage", search: { a: 1 } })}>
     Some Page
   </Link>
   ```
2. Link that replaces existing params:

   ```
   <Link
     to={createPath({ pathname: "/somePage", search: { b: 2 }, merge: false })}
   >
     Some Page
   </Link>
   ```

I'd advise to take this a step further and create a custom `Link` component that does path creation step for you.

Example building on the above utility function:

```
import { Link as LinkBase, LinkProps as BaseLinkProps } from "react-router-dom";

// Override the to prop
interface LinkProps extends Omit<BaseLinkProps, "to"> {
  to: CreatePath;
}

// Use our new createPath utility
const Link = ({ to, ...props }: LinkProps) => (
  <LinkBase to={createPath(to)} {...props} />
);
```

Usage is same as above but now the `to` prop is directly passed:

1. Link that merges params with existing queryString params:

   ```
   <Link to={{ pathname: "/somePage", search: { a: 1 } }}>
     Some Page
   </Link>
   ```
2. Link that replaces existing params:

   ```
   <Link to={{ pathname: "/somePage", search: { b: 2 }, merge: false }}>
     Some Page
   </Link>
   ```

Demo:

[image: Edit how-to-properly-serialize-query-params]

Answer (score 1):

I didn't know `react-router` has anything to do with query either. This is the code that i used before to set it.

```
const _encode = v => {
  if (v === undefined || v === null) return ''
  return encodeURIComponent(v)
}

const queryString = params => Object
  .keys(params)
  .map(key => (_encode(key) + '=' + _encode(params[key])))
  .join('&')
```

Like you said i have to add `?` as well.

my two cents, router doesn't actually support these parameters. Maybe `useQuery` is just a bit handy, but other than that they don't use any of that when setting up the routes.

Answer (score 0):

This is my oneliner solution

```js
import encodeurl from "encodeurl";

Object.entries(inputObject)
    .map(([key, value]) => `${key}=${encodeurl(value)}`)
    .join("&");
```